# Is it possible to have an actual memory leak in Python because of your code?

Tags: python, memory-leaks

I don't have a code example, but I'm curious whether it's possible to write Python code that results in essentially a memory leak.

Comment: You should clarify: are you talking about leaked memory after the process is finished executing; and are you talking about pure Python with no C modules?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

It is possible, yes.

It depends on what kind of memory leak you are talking about. Within pure Python code, it's not possible to "forget to free" memory such as in C, but it is possible to leave a reference hanging somewhere.  Some examples of such:

**An unhandled traceback object that is keeping an entire stack frame alive, even though the function is no longer running**

```
while game.running():
    try:
        key_press = handle_input()
    except SomeException:
        etype, evalue, tb = sys.exc_info()
        # Do something with tb like inspecting or printing the traceback
```

In this silly example of a game loop maybe, we assigned `tb` to a local. We had good intentions, but this `tb` contains frame information about the stack of whatever was happening in our handle_input all the way down to potentially very deep calls, and anything in those stacks. Presuming your game continues, this 'tb' is kept alive even in your next call to handle_input, and maybe forever. The [docs for exc_info](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) now talk about this potential circular reference issue and recommend simply not assigning `tb` if you don't absolutely need it. If you only need to get a traceback consider e.g. [`traceback.format_exc`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exc) instead.

**Storing values in a class or global scope instead of instance scope, and not realizing it.**

This one can happen in insidious ways, but often happens when you define mutable types in your class scope.

```
class Money:
    name = ''
    symbols = []   # This is the dangerous line here

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def add_symbol(self, symbol):
        self.symbols.append(symbol)
```

In the above example, say you did

```
m = Money()
m.set_name('Dollar')
m.add_symbol('$')
```

You'll probably find *this* particular bug quickly. What happened is in this case you put a mutable value at class scope and even though you correctly access it at instance scope, it's actually "falling through" to the *class object*'s `__dict__`.

This used in certain contexts could potentially cause your application's heap to grow forever, and would cause issues in say, a production web application that didn't restart its processes occasionally.

**Cyclic references in classes which also have a `__del__` method.**

*Authors Note - [As of Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.garbage), this issue [is mostly solved by PEP-0442](https://peps.python.org/pep-0442/)*

Ironically, the existence of a `__del__` made it impossible (in Python 2 & early versions of Python 3) for the cyclic garbage collector to clean an instance up. Say you had something where you wanted to do a destructor for finalization purposes:

```
class ClientConnection:
    def __del__(self):
        if self.socket is not None:
            self.socket.close()
            self.socket = None
```

Now this works fine on its own, and you may be led to believe it's being a good steward of OS resources to ensure the socket is 'disposed' of.

However, if ClientConnection kept a reference to say, `User` and User kept a reference to the connection, you might be tempted to say that on cleanup, let's have user de-reference the connection. [This is actually the flaw](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__), however: the [cyclic GC doesn't know the correct order of operations and cannot clean it up](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.garbage).

The solution to this is to ensure you do cleanup on say, disconnect events by calling some sort of close, but name that method something other than `__del__`.

**Poorly implemented C extensions, or not properly using C libraries as they are designed.**

In Python, you trust in the garbage collector to throw away things you aren't using. But if you use an extension that wraps a C library, the majority of the time you are responsible for making sure you explicitly close or de-allocate resources. Mostly this is documented, but a Python programmer who is used to not having to do this explicit de-allocation might throw away the handle to that library or an object within without knowing that resources are being held.

**Scopes which contain closures that contain a whole lot more than you could've anticipated**

```
class User:
    def set_profile(self, profile):
        def on_completed(result):
            if result.success:
                self.profile = profile

        self._db.execute(
            change={'profile': profile},
            on_complete=on_completed
        )
```

In this contrived example, we appear to be using some sort of 'async' call that will call us back at `on_completed` when the DB call is done (the implementation could've been promises, it ends up with the same outcome).

What you may not realize is that the `on_completed` closure binds a reference to `self` in order to execute the `self.profile` assignment. Now, perhaps the DB client keeps track of active queries and pointers to the closures to call when they're done (since it's async) and say it crashes for whatever reason. If the DB client doesn't correctly cleanup callbacks etc, in this case, the DB client now has a reference to on_completed which has a reference to User which keeps a `_db` - you've now created a circular reference that may never get collected.

(Even without a circular reference, the fact that closures bind locals and even instances sometimes may cause values you thought were collected to be living for a long time, which could include sockets, clients, large buffers, and entire trees of things)

**Default parameters which are mutable types**

```
def foo(a=[]):
    a.append(time.time())
    return a
```

This is a contrived example, but one could be led to believe that the default value of `a` being an empty list means append to it, when it is in fact a reference to the *same* list. This again similar to the earlier `Money` example might cause unbounded growth without knowing that you did that.

(*Note from August 2023 Update: This post was originally written in 2010 and the information within is still largely valid today, I just did some minor updates to the URL references and made sure the code examples are valid in both Python 2 & Python 3*)

Comment: Could you elaborate or provide some documentation on your first bullet "an unhandled traceback object that is keeping an entire stack frame alive, even though the function is no longer running"? I actually have a traceback leak but fail to see why it is referenced anywhere (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681681/what-could-prevent-a-traceback-from-being-garbage-collected)

Comment: @BiAiB The plain and simple is that you can have a traceback object stored somewhere. For example, `sys.last_traceback` keeps a reference to the last traceback, and info from `sys.exc_info()` does similar.

This is further complicated with cross-language bindings, etc... I'll jump over to your question and answer more.

Comment: Memory leak is some allocated memory that you lost reference to and by the way it can not be deallocated. Messing up with sys and gc modules would create some memory leaks. I have not been there! I do not want to go either. @Crast `del foo` is sufficient to free allocated memory by `a`. I do not see any memory leak there!

Answer (score 20):

The classic definition of a memory leak is memory that was used once, and now is not, but has not been reclaimed.  That nearly impossible with pure Python code.  But as Antoine points out, you can easily have the effect of consuming all your memory inadvertently by allowing data structures to grow without bound, even if you don't need to keep all of the data around.

With C extensions, of course, you are back in unmanaged territory, and anything is possible.

Answer (score 11):

Of course you can. The typical example of a memory leak is if you build a cache that you never flush manually and that has no automatic eviction policy.

Comment: Technically that's not a memory leak as the application is still **able** to release the memory, although it chooses not to.

Comment: Well I just think we define "memory leak" differently, then. For me a leak is a leak, regardless of whether it is possible to fix it or not.

Comment: If it doesn't have code to remove elements from the cache then it isn't able to remove them, is it?

Comment: I think a memory leak is anything that doesn't release memory when it's done fulfilling its purpose. I wouldn't call an improperly managed cache a memory leak however, only because it's not really done. It's just wasteful.

Comment: By your definition a long-running process cannot have a memory leak until it is "done", which sounds a bit improper to me.

Answer (score 1):

In the sense of orphaning allocated objects after they go out of scope because you forgot to deallocate them, no; Python will automatically deallocate out of scope objects ([Garbage Collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science))). But in the sense that @Antione is talking about, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Since many modules are written  in C , yes, it is possible to have memory leaks.
imagine you are using a gui paint drawing context (eg with wxpython) , you can create memory buffers but if you forgot to release it. you will have memory leaks...
in this case, C++ functions of wx api are wrapped to python.

a bigger wrong usage , imagine you overload these wx widgets methods within python... memoryleaks assured.

Answer (score 0):

I create an object with a heavy attribute to show off in the process memory usage.

Then I create a dictionary which refers itself for a big number of times.

Then I delete the object, and ask GC to collect garrbage. It collects none.

Then I check the process RAM footprint - it is the same.

Here you go, memory leak!

```
α python
Python 2.7.15 (default, Oct  2 2018, 11:47:18)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gc
>>> class B(object):
...     b = list(range(1 * 10 ** 8))
...
>>>
[1]+  Stopped                 python
~/Sources/plan9port [git branch:master]
α ps aux | grep python
alexander.pugachev 85164   0.0 19.0  7562952 3188184 s010  T     2:08pm   0:03.78 /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
~/Sources/plan9port [git branch:master]
α fg
python

>>> b = B()
>>> for i in range(1000):
...     b.a = {'b': b}
...
>>>
[1]+  Stopped                 python
~/Sources/plan9port [git branch:master]
α ps aux | grep python
alexander.pugachev 85164   0.0 19.0  7579336 3188264 s010  T     2:08pm   0:03.79 /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
~/Sources/plan9port [git branch:master]
α fg
python


>>> b.a['b'].a
{'b': <__main__.B object at 0x109204950>}
>>> del(b)
>>> gc.collect()
0
>>>
[1]+  Stopped                 python
~/Sources/plan9port [git branch:master]
α ps aux | grep python
alexander.pugachev 85164   0.0 19.0  7579336 3188268 s010  T     2:08pm   0:05.13 /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
```