# What can cause a memory leak in python?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: Is it possible to have an actual memory leak in Python because of your code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017381/python-is-it-possible-to-have-an-actual-memory-leak-in-python-because-of-your-c)

Since the python garbage collector handles detection of circular references (object A referencing Object B and Object B referencing Object A), I was wondering what could cause a memory leak in python code? Can you provide specific examples of code that would create an  inaccessible region of memory that the garbage collector could not handle or is such a thing impossible?

Any examples appreciated !

Comment: This is homework, right?

Comment: Also, what have you tried to create a memory leak?

Comment: I think you can get answer from this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017381/python-is-it-possible-to-have-an-actual-memory-leak-in-python-because-of-your-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the  [gc — Garbage Collector interface](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html) module,

> #### [`gc.garbage`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.garbage):
>
> **A list of objects which the collector found to be
>   unreachable** but could not be freed (uncollectable objects). By
>   default, this list contains only objects with `__del__()` methods. [[1]](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#id2)
>   Objects that have `__del__()` methods and are part of a reference cycle
>   cause the entire reference cycle to be uncollectable, including
>   objects not necessarily in the cycle but reachable only from it.
>   Python doesn’t collect such cycles automatically because, in general,
>   it isn’t possible for Python to guess a safe order in which to run the
>   `__del__()` methods. If you know a safe order, you can force the issue by examining the garbage list, and explicitly breaking cycles due to
>   your objects within the list. Note that these objects are kept alive
>   even so by virtue of being in the garbage list, so they should be
>   removed from garbage too. For example, after breaking cycles, do `del`
>   `gc.garbage[:]` to empty the list. It’s generally better to avoid the
>   issue by not creating cycles containing objects with `__del__()`.
>   methods, and garbage can be examined in that case to verify that no
>   such cycles are being created.